# interate through file returning dictionary output (python 3). Debugging my UDF

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, debugging

excuse my attempt at explaining my problem.

Declaration: im working in google colab.

My code bloc essentially returns key values based on conditions of the input argument.
Perhaps observing the code may make more sense.

objective: i have a file of 500+ names. All elements within the file are considered proper_nouns (all names of people only). Any other word outside of the file should have an 's' added to the end.

Otherwise:

- If it ends with 'y' and is preceded by a consonant, erase the last letter and add -
  ies.
- If it ends with 'f', erase the last letter and add -ves.
- If it ends with 'sh'/'ch'/'z', add -es.
- If none of the above applies, just add -s.
- After these rules are applied, your output dictionary should be:
- {‘plural’: word_in_plural, ‘status’: ‘success’}

```
filepath = '/proper_noun.txt'
```

```
def pluralize(word):
  proper_nouns= [line.strip() for line in open (filepath)]    ### opens file when function is called, removes white spaces, and returns a list of the content within the file. 
  word_in_plural = ''                                         ### placeholders for string values.
  x = ''
  dictionary = {'plural' : word_in_plural, 'status' : x}      ### dictionary definition
  if word == '':                                              ### returns string value: 'empty_string' if argument is '' 
    dictionary ['plural'] = ''
    dictionary ['status'] = 'empty_string'
  return dictionary
  if word [-1] == 's':                                        ### if word ends with 's', returns 'already_in_plural'
    dictionary ['plural'] = word
    dictionary ['status'] = 'already_in_plural'
  return dictionary
  if word in proper_nouns:                                    ### if word is found in txt. file, returns 'proper_noun'
    dictionary ['plural'] = word
    dictionary ['status'] = 'proper_noun'
  return dictionary
```

this is where im up to as of now.

when i call the function *pluralize(word)*, the output stops working after it passes the first *if* statement. Empty strings returns correctly however the two statements following have suddenly stopped working when i input a word that, lets say, ends with 's' or use a word found in txt.. 'jean'

it returns

```
pluralize('jean')
{'plural': '', 'status': ''}
pluralize('jeans')
{'plural': '', 'status': ''}
```

thank you for your time

Comment: `filepath` in your loop at the first line, does not give you the contents of your file. Replace `filepath` with `open(filepath, 'r').readlines()`. Also, your title has a typo and your question asks about your usecase, with you could easily break down to smaller questions and a simple search stackoverflow should give all the answers you need.

Comment: I think i implemented your suggestion?


`proper_nouns= [line.strip() for line in open (filepath, 'r').readlines()]`

Comment: check what you have in "line".

Comment: nothing.. this aint good.
`proper_nouns= [open (filepath, 'r').readlines()] `
printing proper_nouns prompts 'not defined'

Comment: Here's my suggestion: just open the file and read it with readlines like I said. This will give you a list. Your posted code DOES NOT do this. Once you have the content as a list of lines, you could build on top of that. Write small blocks and test first. Only then progress to next part. If I were you, I would use something like Jupyter notebook for quick interactive development (that's my personal preference).

Comment: See this: https://realpython.com/read-write-files-python/

Comment: would love to but im resticted to google colab since thats my institution's preference. will try to simply this. Thing is,, it genuinely read the file multiple times. Now suddenly, its not. Ive checked the directory and i seems fine.

Comment: @CypherX The OP's oriiginal code works perfectly fine. File objects are iterable, so using `readlines()` is redundant.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks for checking that. If that's the case, great.

Comment: @user14519115 You need remove the first two `return dictionary` lines, otherwise the function will terminate too early.

Comment: @user14519115 Colab should work just fine. Your code is not properly formatted. Indent the return statements: they should be within your if blocks.

Comment: The other option is: you keep just one return statement at the very end of your function (like @ekhumoro suggested).

Comment: @user14519115 PS: you should also change the last two if's to elif's.

Comment: @ekhumoro thanks for your time. That cleans things up nicely! Cheers pal